# Connect two polygons in GeoJSON

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas, snapping

I have 2 polygons on the map. How connect them more beautifully in the corners? Now there is a collision between them.

```
    {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -56.39684218705685,
              69.23654801567378
            ],
            [
              -56.86959694088712,
              68.89141492143585
            ],
            [
              -57.328464194202844,
              68.54510688650751
            ],
            [
              -57.77406279553318,
              68.1976788855316
            ],
            [
              -58.20697818784977,
              67.84918260591532
            ],
            [
              -58.6277644079531,
              67.49966667681876
            ],
            [
              -59.03694596688591,
              67.14917688042829
            ],
            [
              -59.43501961661234,
              66.7977563470219
            ],
            [
              -59.82245600845029,
              66.44544573515968
            ],
            [
              -60.199701248954355,
              66.0922833981506
            ],
            [
              -66.25285269227511,
              66.98715777189786
            ],
            [
              -65.95334466261691,
              67.35192553566114
            ],
            [
              -65.64589349263761,
              67.71571969246442
            ],
            [
              -65.32970119808897,
              68.0790043550096
            ],
            [
              -65.00433787920183,
              68.44175507044689
            ],
            [
              -64.6693460337937,
              68.80394573484732
            ],
            [
              -64.32423839160383,
              69.16554845592137
            ],
            [
              -63.96849555162967,
              69.52653340224435
            ],
            [
              -63.6015634025919,
              69.88686863754444
            ],
            [
              -63.222850304771086,
              70.24651993817815
            ],
            [
              -62.83108076109499,
              70.60602987128148
            ],
            [
              -55.91113420544609,
              69.57934546957146
            ],
            [
              -56.39684218705685,
              69.23654801567378
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "id": "770"
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -50.80217864942013,
              72.58951789677091
            ],
            [
              -50.80563285094532,
              72.58781645236614
            ],
            [
              -51.45821883091744,
              72.2596572885238
            ],
            [
              -51.46155846970803,
              72.25794293954921
            ],
            [
              -52.09179123039377,
              71.927814780633
            ],
            [
              -52.09502192560654,
              71.92608800177456
            ],
            [
              -52.70398802856058,
              71.59409617689144
            ],
            [
              -52.70711508930415,
              71.59235740607093
            ],
            [
              -53.295840917480646,
              71.25860030038703
            ],
            [
              -53.29886935917183,
              71.25684994144544
            ],
            [
              -53.868324340478196,
              70.92141950951003
            ],
            [
              -53.871258900815235,
              70.91965793467062
            ],
            [
              -54.42235863959781,
              70.58264017420416
            ],
            [
              -54.4252037939961,
              70.58086772635906
            ],
            [
              -54.958813093042295,
              70.24234311532135
            ],
            [
              -54.96157306952036,
              70.24056011011977
            ],
            [
              -55.47850883070973,
              69.90060400978001
            ],
            [
              -55.481187624111364,
              69.89881073757147
            ],
            [
              -55.982221620320765,
              69.55749376408829
            ],
            [
              -62.76723050047888,
              70.62341104160771
            ],
            [
              -62.36305511148472,
              70.98205768845831
            ],
            [
              -61.946130966722045,
              71.33896001248874
            ],
            [
              -61.514634702453485,
              71.69502181134081
            ],
            [
              -61.06773552404944,
              72.05019397925854
            ],
            [
              -60.60454170388716,
              72.40442356232137
            ],
            [
              -60.124095263735825,
              72.75765338980787
            ],
            [
              -59.62536614323812,
              73.10982166446726
            ],
            [
              -59.10724580473613,
              73.46086150659555
            ],
            [
              -58.56854022122615,
              73.81070044608515
            ],
            [
              -58.00646644180655,
              74.16016771770492
            ],
            [
              -50.126089418574,
              72.9155952367825
            ],
            [
              -50.80217864942013,
              72.58951789677091
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "id": "771"
    }
  
  ],
  "bbox": [
    -180,
    -83.85436044327008,
    205.05505252762117,
    83.85140481615035
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can edit them in QGis in the same way as any other dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [snap](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#snapping) one to the other:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import snap

df = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/connect.json")
geom1=df.iloc[0].geometry
geom2=df.iloc[1].geometry

#Snaps vertices in geom1 to vertices in the geom2
geom1_snapped = snap(geom1, geom2, 0.1)

df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[geom1_snapped, geom2], crs=4326)
df2.to_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/connect_snapped.json")
```

[image]